# What is the name of this operation on column vectors?

Tags: matrices, vectors

Is there a name for this operation?

Or is there a combination of other operations on matrices that if

```
A = [a1, a2, .., an]
```

```
B = [b1, b2, .., bm]
```

```
C = [[a1 * b1, a1 * b2, .., a1 * bm],
    [ a2 * b1, a2 * b2, .., a2 * bm],
    [ ..,      ..,      .., ..     ],
    [ an * b1, an * b2, .., an * bm]]
```

then

```
A ? B = C
```

Comment: This is called the outer product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

Comment: We have $A^TB = C$. That is, $C$ is `A.T @ B`.

Comment: Thanks friends. This is what you need.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer fully so that I can mark it.